# Migration issues to JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: migration, jboss7.x

I am migrating application from JBoss AS 4.X to JBoss AS 7.1. I am facing the following problem

I have a userdefined xml which has some configuration related stuff like paths, initial load setting etc which I used to place in `Application Server/bin` in JBoss AS 4.X. It was working fine.

Now i placed the same file in `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin` but it is not working and loading on start up of server.

Where do I need to keep such XML's in 7.1 Server?
And do I need to explicitly mention in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`?

Comment: Who access this file? The application code?

Comment: yes the application code

Comment: Follow this link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897339/jboss-7-1-development-issues/21107215#21107215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try writing a custom [module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home) and place the xml file there. And then make your application depend on this module.

**Edit:**

The following Wiki page outlines it nicely [How to put an external file in the classpath](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath)