# JBoss 7 - using *.properties files from filesystem

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a webapplication (maven,spring,,hibernate) which contains different *.properties files which can be found within src/main/resource. Now my customer want to edit this files (e.g. change email address..) --> whats the best solution/ best practise? exclude *.properties from .war file and put it into filesystem? Jboss modules?

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd move these properties from static files to a persistent storage (i.e. DB) and then provide a UI to end user to modify their values.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I already thought about this solution but what would be a possible solution to access the stored properties from my applicationContext.xml? I use spring and I need to access, for example, the ldap property to set LdapContextSource within my applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a custom module might work. This isn't as bad as it sounds, check out [HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath).

See also [migration-issues-to-jboss-7-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400280/migration-issues-to-jboss-7-1) and [Where to put property file in JBOSS 7 or Glassflish? (Best practice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562069/where-to-put-property-file-in-jboss-7-or-glassflish-best-practice/)

Comment: I have to add that the applications runs in a cluster.